# ジェネリックの引数で作られているメソッドに指定したオブジェクトのプロパティのみ取得する方法

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

以下のコードでbメソッドで取得した引数testのプロパティを1つのみ取得したいのですが、実現可能でしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

```
    public void a()
    {
        b<test>(new test{ a = 1 });
    }

    public void b<T>(T test)
    {
        // test.GetType().GetProperties()にて取得できる値が以下
        // {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[2]}
        // [0] [PropertyInfo]:{Int32 a}
        // [1] [PropertyInfo]:{System.String b}

        // 本当は引数で指定した値のみ取得したい！
        // {System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[1]}
        // [0] [PropertyInfo]:{Int32 a}
    }

    class test
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public string b { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

前提としてC#では呼び出し元でどのような処理を行っているか呼び出し側から判定することは出来ません。ですので正確に判断する方法はありません。

ですが.NET Frameworkには`PropertyDescriptor`という仕組みがあり、これによって特定のプロパティが変更されているかどうかを知ることが出来ます。まずプロパティの定義に既定の値を

```
using System.ComponentModel;
class test
{
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int a { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

のように`DefaultValueAttribute`で指定しておけば、`PropertyDescriptor.ShouldSerializeValue`でこの値から変更されているかどうかが分かりますので、これを利用して

```
public void a()
{
    b<test>(new test { a = 1 });
    b<test>(new test { b = "1" });
    b<test>(new test { a = 0, b = null });
}

public void b<T>(T test)
{
    var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(test);
    var pd = properties.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ShouldSerializeValue(test));
    Console.WriteLine(pd?.Name ?? "null");
}
```

のように`ShouldSerializeValue`が`true`となっているプロパティを探すことが出来ます。ただ最後の例のように既定値自体が設定されている場合は`false`となりますので、これを検出するにはプロパティの`set`でフラグを立ててやるような実装が必要になるかと思います。

Comment: ご丁寧にご回答ありがとうございます！今回のケースでは、クラス側の加工はせずにプロパティの変更が出来ないかと思っていたのですが、ほぼ不可能であることがわかったため勉強になりました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: 一応プロパティの既定値が`default(T)` (`null`または`0`)であると決めつけてそれらと比較する方法もあります

Comment: >default(T) (nullまたは0)であると決めつけてそれらと比較する方法
まさにこのような仕組みでライブラリを作ってたんですが、「既定値が来たときどうすんのよ？」って思って困りました(笑)
考え方を変えて、Typeじゃなくてobjectを使う方法をオーバーライドしようかなと検討しています泣